# How to know thread ID for each thread spawn by Parallel.Foreach

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I have a scenario something like this:

```
int arr[100];

Parallel.Foreach(arr, (a) => { some processing});
```

Now, this code will spawn 100 child threads. How can I know thread ID for each child thread in "some processing" logic?

Comment: This will not spawn 100 child threads it will simply execute 100 times possibly even using a single thread.

Comment: This won't spawn 100 threads. Always remember: more threads does NOT necessarily mean better performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use

```
Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
```

but note that your parallel foreach is not *forced* to actually create 100 threads.